# How to find the normal of a complex shape(more than 4 vertices) and apply lighting on it?

Tags: opengl

im currently trying to apply lighting on a complex shape drawn with the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP flag. since every plane in the XYZ can be defined by 3 points calculating the normal can be quite easy, but what happens when i use gl_triangle_strip?

just to make the following code more readable, the drawing process goes like this :
(x,y) -> (x+1 , y) -> (x , y+1) -> (x+1 , y+1)

```
for(int i = 0; i < m_GraphConfig.MAXY   ; i +=2)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int j = 0; j < m_GraphConfig.MAXX  ;j+=2)
    {
        if ( (i * m_GraphConfig.MAXX + j + 2) % (m_GraphConfig.MAXX) != 0 && (i+2) % (m_GraphConfig.MAXY) != 0  && (j + 2) % (m_GraphConfig.MAXX) != 0  )
        {
            index = i * (m_GraphConfig.MAXX) + j;
            heightVal = host[index];
            glColor3b(((heightVal % 32) * 7 %255), ((heightVal % 16) * 14) %255, ((heightVal % 128) * 2)%255);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);   
            glVertex3d(xFactor * j , host[index] /m_GraphConfig.devider  , zFactor * i);

            index = i * (m_GraphConfig.MAXX) + j + 2;
            heightVal = host[index];
            glColor3b(((heightVal % 32) * 7)%255, ((heightVal % 16) * 14)%255, ((heightVal % 128) * 2)%255);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);   
            glVertex3d(xFactor * (j + 2) , host[index] / m_GraphConfig.devider, zFactor * i);

            index = i * (m_GraphConfig.MAXX) + j + (2 * m_GraphConfig.MAXX);
            heightVal = host[index];
            glColor3b(((heightVal % 32) * 7)%255, ((heightVal % 16) * 14)%255, ((heightVal % 128) * 2)%255);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);   
            glVertex3d(xFactor * j , host[index] / m_GraphConfig.devider , zFactor * (i + 2));

            index = i * (m_GraphConfig.MAXX) + j + (2 * m_GraphConfig.MAXX) + 2;
            heightVal = host[index];
            glColor3b(((heightVal % 32) * 7)%255, ((heightVal % 16) * 14)%255, ((heightVal % 128) * 2)%255);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);   
            glVertex3d(xFactor * ( j + 2) , host[index] / m_GraphConfig.devider , zFactor * (i + 2));           
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 ); //clear the texture buffer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It much depends on your usage of it. Is it a flat surface (e.g. cylinder bottom) or a curvy shape (e.g. cylinder side)

For the first case you can calculate normal for every triangle in the strip and use average of all of them for the polygon.

For the second case you need to split the triangle strip into triangles and treat/render them separately one by one. If you want to keep the smoothshading and triangle strip then you will need to calculate and use per-vertice normals (which are averages of all triangles normals that use this vertice)

Comment: You don't need to average them in the first case, as they lie on a plane, so the normal is the same for all of them.  Any one of the normals will do for all of them.

Comment: Thats true for most of the cases. However it is often that polygons are not entirely planar when imported from 3D modelling apps (e.g. happens when modelling biological objects with quads). Better be safe.